# Auto resizing images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this site I've been doing as a hobby and I ran into an issue which I can't find a solution for.

site: josesebastianmanunta.com/daniel

PROBLEM: in the code below I am using % for my widths for resizing which works, but when resized the img in `.sec1` resizes but does not resize properly. It does not match the height for the `.sideslides`. Also it is my first time on here. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. Thanks! All code can be seen through browser.

Problem code:

```
<div id="sec1_and_side">
    <div class="sec1">
    <img src="images/dan.jpg"  id="dan"/>
    </div>
    <div class="sideslides">
        <div class="sec sideslider">
            <img src="images/feature-3.jpg" id="feature3" class="img1"/>
            <img src="images/newfeature/piece5.jpg" class="img2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="sec sideslider">
            <img src="images/feature-4.jpg" id="feature4" class="img1"/>
            <img src="images/newfeature/piece4.jpg" class="img2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="sec sideslider">
            <img src="images/feature-5.jpg" id="feature5" class="img1"/>
            <img src="images/newfeature/piece3.jpg" class="img2"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What effect are you actually after?  Are you wanting the height of sec1 to always match the height of sideslides?  Rather than quote a live site which might change over time, perhaps use jsfiddle.net that allows saving of HTML, CSS and Javascript, and post a link to that.

Comment: Sorry, I see the effect you are after now. Main image, plus 3 images to the right, and two images, side by side, underneath.  But the height of the main image is not matching the 3 images to the right.

Answer (score 0):

To make the height of the main image match the height of the 3 images to the right, the main image needs to be a bit bigger. Approximately 6px bigger, to match the padding gaps in the panels on the right.

Use an image editor to resize the canvas by 6px at the top, and fill with white.

You could try fixing it with CSS by adding the following, but it won't resize very well. Mixing absolute px with percentages never gives good results.

```
.sec1 {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    padding-top: 6px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Update: At maximum size, you'll notice a gap between the top and the first image in the right column.  This is because the images in the right column have a max-height.  To combat this, and allow the height of the main image to match the right column, put a `max-height` on `.sec1`.  Using the CSS solution, this `max-height` would be 375px, to take into account the padding-top.  Using a resized image solution, it would be 381px (125px * 3 + 3px * 2).